# Is there a shortcut to this combination problem?

Tags: permutations, combinations

The question I have encountered is:

From 4 oranges, 3 bananas and 2 apples, how many selections of 5 pieces of fruit can be made, taking at least 1 of each kind?

So the method I used to solve this problem was finding every combination of each case like shown below:

```
Oranges   Bananas   Apples
   1         2        2         = 4C1 x 3C2 x 2C2
   1         3        1         = 4C1 x 3C3 x 2C1
   2         1        2         = 4C2 x 3C1 x 2C2
   2         2        1         = 4C2 x 3C2 x 2C1
   3         1        1         = 4C3 x 3C1 x 2C1
```

And then, I had to add all of them up to get the final result, 98, which was the correct answer. However, it felt kind of time taking for me, so I wondering if there's any shortcut to solving this problem. Please help :D thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to count instead might be to take the total number of selections, then subtract out each selection that fails to have at least one of each kind.  Note that each selection of five has at least two kinds, so the formula is:

- (# choices with at least one of each) 
      = (total # of choices) - (# of choices without apples) - (# of choices without oranges) - (# of choices without bananas)

This is counted as
$$
\binom{9}{5} - \binom{7}{5} - \binom{6}{5} - \binom{5}{5} = 126 - 21-6-1 = 98
$$

Comment: Yup, that is waaaaaaay better and simpler than my way. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Here's an alternate method:

$$(2C1 \times 3C1 \times 4C3) + (2C1 \times 3C2 \times 4C2) + (2C1 \times 3C3 \times 4C1) + (2C2 \times 3C1 \times 4C2) + (2C2 \times 3C2 \times 4C1)$$

$$= (2 \times 3 \times 4) + (2 \times 3 \times 6) + (2 \times 1 \times 4) + (1 \times 3 \times 6) + (1 \times 3 \times 4) $$

$$=24 + 36 + 8 + 18 + 12 $$

$$= 98$$

Another method:

Total combinations without any restrictions = 9C5 = 126 
Therefore, if you apply condition such as the one above the total combination will be less than 126.

Selections with at least 1 of each of the fruit = at least 1 + at least 2

or

Total combinations - selection consisting of exactly 2 fruit. [here exactly 1 fruit cannot be possible since we have to make 5 selections, and maximum number of fruit of one type is 4]

Bananas + Oranges = 3+4 = 7 = 7C5 = 21 
Oranges + Apples = 3+2 = 5 = 5C5 = 1 
Apples + Bananas = 4+2 = 6 = 6C5 = 6

21+1+6 = 28

total combinations = 126

Selections with at least 1 of each of the fruit = 126 - 28 = 98

Comment: Your way works as well! thanks!